# Python asyncio e threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread, assincronismo, thread-safety

Estou estudando o módulo `asyncio` do `Python` e existe a função *[run_coroutine_threadsafe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe)* que deve ser executado numa thread diferente daquela que está o loop de eventos. Segue meu script:

```
#!usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import asyncio
import threading


def target():
    print('Iniciou a thread')
    #asyncio.set_event_loop(None)
    #loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(blah(), loop)
    print('Finalizou a thread')


async def blah():
    print('Thread atual:', threading.current_thread().name)


async def main():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=target, args=(), kwargs={}, name='Minha Thread')
    thread.setDaemon(True)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
    print('finalizou')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    finally:
        loop.close()

# Output
Iniciou a thread
Finalizou a thread
finalizando
```

O problema é que a corotina `blah` nunca é invocada pelo função `run_coroutine_threadsafe` mas não consigo encontrar o motivo, tentei até mesmo instanciar um novo loop de eventos (como podem ver nas linhas comentadas) mas nem mesmo assim o script funciona. O que estou errando?

Comment: Não houve saída no terminou.

Comment: Troquei os `print` pelo `sys.stdout.write` mas nem mesmo assim funcionou.

Comment: Devo ter me enganado sobre isso. Desculpe-me.

Comment: Que isso eu agradeço por estar tentando me ajudar.

Comment: Pelo o que entendi, lendo por cima a documentação, você não precisa criar uma *thread* para isso, a própria função `run_coroutine_threadsafe` irá executar em outra *thread*.

Comment: Eu também achei que sim, mas quando executo fazendo a chamada de `run_coroutine_threadsafe` da `MainThread` o resultado impresso é `"MainThread"`, ele não cria outra `thread`, pesquisando encontrei na documentação uma função `run_in_executor` que faz a criação de outra `thread`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está chamando `loop.close()` antes de ele ter a oportunidade de rodar a rotina `blah`.

A rotina `blah` está agendada para execução no loop, porém a thread principal (que tem o loop) está presa em `main()`... Ela nunca cedeu controle ao loop para que ele rode outras rotinas, e quando `main()` termina o loop é fechado.

Por exemplo, colocando 1 segundo de espera antes de terminar o loop:

```
...
thread.join()
await asyncio.sleep(1)
print('finalizou')
...
```

Coloque esse `await sleep` em `main()` entre o `join()` e o `print` como no exemplo e vai ter o resultado que você espera. Pois o `await` devolve o controle para o loop.

Um outro exemplo é usar um evento para sinalizar o fim do programa:

```
import asyncio
import threading

def target(e):
    print('Iniciou a thread')
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(blah(e), loop)
    print('Finalizou a thread')

async def blah(e):
    print('Thread atual:', threading.current_thread().name)
    e.set() # sinaliza o final da rotina, autorizando o loop a terminar


async def main():
    e = asyncio.Event()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=target, args=(e,), kwargs={}, name='Minha Thread')
    thread.setDaemon(True)
    thread.start()
    await e.wait() # devolve o controle ao loop e espera que
                   # a rotina sinalize o fim do programa
    print('finalizou')
```

Dessa forma antes de terminar o loop, esperamos pela execução da rotina `blah` usando um evento `asyncio.Event()`.

Comment: A espera da finalização da `thread` com o método `join()` ocorre somente se o controle for retornado ao `event loop`?

Comment: Quer dizer que mesmo que eu agende uma `corotina` numa `thread` diferente se o `event loop` for o mesmo preciso ceder o controle ao loop de eventos para que a mesma seja executada?

Comment: @ThiagoLuizS Primeira pergunta: não, você pode retirar o `join()` que vai funcionar do mesmo jeito. O que você não pode fazer é terminar o loop... O seu loop tem que ficar ativo, sempre esperando alguma coisa - no exemplo foi o `sleep` mas num programa real o loop provavelmente fica a maior parte do tempo esperando por io.

Comment: @ThiagoLuizS segunda pergunta: Você usa `run_coroutine_threadsafe`  para agendar uma corotina que será executada na thread principal, quando o loop tiver tempo pra isso. O erro do seu código foi somente ter finalizado o loop - geralmente o loop fica esperando algo acontecer, até terminar tudo que o programa tem que fazer.  Quando não tiver mais o que esperar, aí sim você chama `loop.close()`.

Comment: Se `run_coroutine_threadsafe` é executada na `MainThread` qual o motivo do mesmo ser `threadsafe`?

Comment: @ThiagoLuizS rotinas assíncronas só rodam na thread principal, onde o loop está - se você tem outras threads que precisam iniciar rotinas assíncronas, precisa usar isso para agendar a execução de algo na thread principal.

Comment: Tenho que chamar esse método da `MainThread` e como será executado em outra `thread` ?

Comment: @ThiagoLuizS `run_coroutine_threadsafe` pode ser executado de qualquer thread. A corotina que você passar, vai rodar no loop, ou seja, vai rodar na main thread.

Comment: Então `run_coroutine_threadsafe` é invocado em outra `thread` fazendo com que uma `corotina` rode no `event loop` da `MainThread` ?

Comment: @ThiagoLuizS sim, como objetos assíncronos e objetos de corotina não são *threadsafe*, você precisa usar `run_coroutine_threadsafe` toda vez que precisar rodar algo no loop, porque você está em outra thread e as corotinas precisam ser executados na thread principal onde o loop está. Para isso que existe essa função `run_coroutine_threadsafe` - para permitir rodar tarefas assíncronas a partir de uma thread que não é a mesma onde o loop está.

Comment: Entendi. Muitíssimo obrigado por tudo.